# getOrbit().disable() is not defined

Tags: javascript, graphics

So I am using this library https://dev.codemotionkids.com/libraries/diorama/docs/index.html

I wanted to use the function getOrbit().disable() to disable the camera rotation. However I face this error:

Uncaught TypeError: getOrbit(...).disable is not a function
at draw (sketch.js:166:14)
at _main.default.redraw (p5.js:70809:27)
at _draw (p5.js:63046:25)

If anybody, given that library understand where I am making the error, thank you. I also tried it in one of the examples provided but still had the same problem. If anybody knows how to fix it thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution it is:

```
getOrbit().enabled = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [source code](https://dev.codemotionkids.com/libraries/diorama/docs/index.js.html#line438), I can't see any `enable()` or `disable()`, `getOrbit()` only returns the value of `orbit`. Is it possible for you to use the original [OrbitControl](https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/en/controls/OrbitControls) from three.js?